# Munkres Analysis on Manifolds: Ex 1.3: Why does the example not contradict with the given theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

As it is also asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476822/set-of-infinite-tuples-is-closed-bounded-non-compact), in an example in the book *Analysis of Manifold* by Munkres,

It is given a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is closed and bounded, but not compact.

However, in the book it is stated that

> Theorem 4.9: If $X$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n $, then $X$ is compact.

**So why does the example and the theorem not contradict with each other ?**

Comment: Maybe the topology defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is different.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya Good point. The theorem assumes the standard topology.

Comment: That's not a subset of any $\Bbb R^n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I faced the same problem while understanding $\mathbb{R}$ with Usual topology and Co-countable topology.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is also a good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example, we have a metric space ($\mathbb{R}^\infty$) which is *not* $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, and a subset $X$ which is closed, bounded but not compact. There is no way this could contradict the theorem that says that, with respect to the usual distance, every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is closed and bounded must be compact.